# QR Code Generator Redirecting Incorrectly

Tags: facebook, mobile, tabs, qr-code

I have built a custom tab for a page. This tab have a specific URL:
http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE?sk=app_ID

When I create a QR code for this URL and use my mobile, I'm not redirected to my specific URL but to http://m.facebook.com/MYPAGE?refsrc=http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE&_rds

Any idea about what is wrong with this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[image: QR Code]

Made with http://createqrcode.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks to your answer but it's not my problem :) My problem is the rewritting url of Facebook m.facebook.com. I would like to stay on http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE?sk=app_ID

Comment: Well, the link I gave you at the end is for generating QR Codes, you must simply enter the URL you want a QR for.

Comment: Yes but when i scan this QR with a mobile, i'm not redirect to this URL because FB rewrite this url : http://m.facebook.com/MYPAGE?refsrc=http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE&_rds

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will **always** redirect mobile phones to the mobile version of the site. Your best bet is to find out what the mobile URL is and use that in QR code.