# QR Code Redirecting Incorrectly On Mobile

Tags: facebook, tabs, qr-code

I have built a custom tab for a page. This tab have a specific URL: http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE?sk=app_ID

When I create a QR code for this URL and use my mobile, I'm not redirected to my specific URL but to http://m.facebook.com/MYPAGE?refsrc=http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE&_rds

I would like to be redirected to my specific URL when i flash this code.

How can i fix this problem to be redirected to the correct URL without be redirected to m.facebook.com... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QR Code Generator Redirecting Incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537646/qr-code-generator-redirecting-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will automatically detect the User Agent and redirect to the mobile version of that URL.

The problem you're facing is that Page Tabs don't exist on mobile, so the system is just falling back to the page.

I'm not aware of a workaround.